# Les guillemets et les citations

Tags: guillemets

Bonjour,

> [...]
>
> - Il clôture la séance en posant la question « serez-vous prêts? ».
> - A-t-il vraiment posé la question « serez-vous prêts? »?
>
> Fréquemment, une citation coulée dans une phrase commence par un
> ***fragment de phrase***, puis se prolonge par une ou plusieurs ***phrases
> complètes***. Le signe de ponctuation final de la dernière phrase
> appartient à la citation :
>
> - L’auteur ajoute que, dans notre métier, « il faut douter. C’est le début de la sagesse. »

([BtB](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap%3Flang=fra&lettr=chapsect7&info0=7))

À mon avis, il serait plus logique d'écrire une majuscule dans "serez" et "il", car il s'agit d'une nouvelle phrase. Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Comment: @Zéhontée Bonteuse À mon avis, il est plus clair maintenant, en tout cas, c'est le même que chez BtB.

Comment: C'est un cas où les articles sont superflus: ***Guillemets et citations*** aurait pu faire l'affaire aussi.

Comment: @jlliagre Penses-tu que sans article le titre est plus beau ? J'ai l'impression qu'avec il est plus "sérieux", a plus de poids. En tous cas, BtB a choisi de le garder.

Comment: Plus "beau" peut-être pas mais je le trouve moins "lourd", un peu comme *Crime et Châtiment* et plus élégant que *Le crime et le châtiment*.

Answer (score 3):

Il ne faut pas mettre de majuscule à la phrase entre guillemets si ce n'est pas une phrase complète. Il faut en mettre un si c'est une phrase complète qui doit alors être introduite par un deux-point.

Extrait du « Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale »

[image]

Comment: Merci ! Mais _Serez-vous prêts ?_ est une phrase complète, c'est une question. Votre manuel donne un exemple semblable au bas de la page. _Cessez donc de répéter "**P**ourquoi ?"_ Par contre, dans _Duhamel écrit du livre qu'il est "l'ami de la solitude"_, là, oui, il faut une minuscule.

Comment: Ce n'est pas une phrase complète car sinon, la citation aurait débuté par une majuscule.

Comment: @Personne Oui, une phrase sans verbe qui demande une majuscule comme dans la phrase au bas de la page (Pourquoi ?). Sinon, pourquoi jlliagre revendique ses majuscules dans les titres.

Comment: @Oreste … en fait cela semble venir de l'écriture et de la mise en page des dialogues qui impose un paragraphe pour chaque interlocuteur ; le tiret quadratin indique l'incise (qui peut être sans verbe) autorisant la majuscule au milieu d'une phrase morcelée entre les différents paragraphes : « — Vous allez me dire [*on lui coupe la parole*] — Rien du tout ! — À l'aide — … »